# Error running Django in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am a Python noob and just recently cloned a Django project into PyCharm. I got it all set up with Django support and located the settings.py and manage.py but I get these traceback errors when I tried running the project.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x00000000044CC048>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Public\...\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\Public\...\views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from fproject.lib import hash, userhandler, enum, session, mail
  File "C:\Users\Public\...\lib\hash.py", line 3, in <module>
    import bcrypt
ImportError: No module named 'bcrypt'
```

I'm not sure what any of these errors are telling me. Am I missing modules or are they located in the wrong directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install [bcrypt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/1.0.1). You can do it from command line by runing `pip install bcrypt` or with [IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html).